# vba code to get a time interval between two times

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

raw Data that need to filter
Need an help on filtering the value between two times for example start time will be 00:00 to 14:00, I need to filter those in between values and copy the corresponding data and paste in a another sheet

```
Option Explicit

Sub Filter_My_Data()

Dim Data_sh As Worksheet
Dim Filter_Criteria_Sh As Worksheet
Dim Output_sh As Worksheet

Set Data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set Filter_Criteria_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter_Criteria")
Set Output_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

Output_sh.UsedRange.Clear
Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False

Dim timelist() As long
Dim n As Integer

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Filter_Criteria_Sh.Range("A:A")) - 2

ReDim timelist(n) As long
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To n
    timelist(i) = Filter_Criteria_Sh.Range("A" & i + 2)
Next i

Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 3, timelist(), xlFilterValues
Data_sh.UsedRange.Copy Output_sh.Range("A1")
Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False

MsgBox ("Data has been Copied")

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having with the code you posted?  It's easier if we don't have to guess.

Comment: I have used the above code to get the text values, but i need to filter the time values between 00:00 and 14:00, above code is not working

Comment: Does your dataset have times only, or date-time values?  Some sample data or a screenshot would be useful here. Try recording a macro while filtering the data manually and see what it produces.

Comment: My dataset contains multiple values, i need to filter those values based on the start and end time. Cant able to share the screenshot of the data since its a confidential data. Will share what will look in few minutes.

Comment: What exactly is in column `A` of `Filter_Criteria` and in column `B` (if that's the 2nd column) of `Data`? Dates, times, or strings? In which cells are the `00:00` and `14:00` located? Are they a date or a string?

Comment: Col A contains Name, Col b contains Date, Column C contains Time, other columns contains values that corresponding to the data. I need to filter the values corresponding to time given like from 00:00 to 14:00. I have tried the above code to get that value but i am not getting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Filter By Time Interval

```vb
Sub FilterByTimeInterval()
    
    Const StartString As String = "00:00:00"
    Const EndString As String = "14:00:00"
    
    Dim StartCrit As String: StartCrit = ">=" & CDate(StartString)
    Dim EndCrit As String: EndCrit = "<=" & CDate(EndString)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Data")
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off AutoFilter
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.UsedRange
    
    srg.AutoFilter 3, StartCrit, xlAnd, EndCrit
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Output")
    dws.UsedRange.Clear
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("A1")
    
    srg.Copy dfCell
    
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```